# Can I trade ETH from a private blockchain on to a public blockchain?

Tags: wallets, trading

say I buy a certain amount of ETH per private blockchain and move my assets to my ETH wallet. Do I then have the option to trade those (private) ETH on a public blockchain, using the same wallet as before?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if someone is willing to trade with you, then you can trade those. This has numerous issues:

1. Nobody is willing to pay anything for your private Eths. They are worthless - at least to someone else
2. There is no built-in integration between your blockchain and the public blockchains. You would have to create some sort of integration yourself, at least for trading. Unless you just trade them OTC.

Comment: To 1): They are worthless because there is no public ledger backing up the credibility of those private assets? (there is a ledger obv. in the prv. blockchain, but not publicly verifiable)

Comment: Follow-up question: Is it then at all possible to move assets outside prv. blockchain unto a public one, without exchanging it for real currency (USD, EUR) in between?

Comment: It's not a matter of credibility so much. It's a matter of supply and demand: there is no demand for your private Eths, which means nobody wants to buy them. And, no, it's quite unlikely that you'd be able to trade your private assets to public assets because there is no demand for them - unless they are worth something to someone somewhere

Comment: What if the currency on the private blockchain is just the same as in an existing, public one, say standard ETH?

Comment: If you have further questions, please post a new question or browse the existing questions. But, no, if there's no demand then there's no demand.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, there's no mechanism for transferring your private ETH to a public blockchain and there would not be 3rd party demand for your private blockchain assets.

If you want your private ETH to have same value a public ETH you can create your own bridging mechanism where you have a contract on public ETH blockchain which is able to receive real ETH and, on that basis, mint private ETH to your blockchain. Then your private ETH would be backed 1:1 with real ETH and become transferable across the two chains.

Comment: Do you have some real world examples for that bridging mechanism between private and public blockchain?